# How to connect hearing aids?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, headphones, monterey

I recently got a pair of Phonak hearing aids which come with Bluetooth.
These can be paired with up to 8 devices and connected to 2.
[Phonak User Guide](https://www.phonak.com/content/dam/phonakpro/gc_us/en/resources/digital-journey/PH_User_Guide_myPhonak_app_4.0_297x210_EN_V1.02.pdf)

I have paired with my iMac, iPhone & iPad and work (although obviously I only use one at a time).

I have no problem connecting to iPhone or iPad but connection to the Mac is problematic.

When freshly booted I can connect, but if I ever disconnect e.g. by using inbuilt Mac microphone I can't seem to reconnect, unless I reboot (which takes ages).

Attempts show "Connection rejected"

This apparently is a Bluetooth issue, rather than hearing aid, as I have similar issues with my Powerbeats earphones which I used previously.

Can I force connection WITHOUT restart?

Comment: Is there a manual for these that shows pairing steps to make the Bluetooth discoverable on the aids? On macOS the steps to make Bluetooth discoverable is to open the Bluetooth preference pane. ( I suppose it’s [three steps if you check the docs](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/connect-a-bluetooth-device-blth1004/mac) )

Comment: There is a manual, and I had paired - which worked. It still shows as paired BUT won't let me connect! Surely it is possible to switch between a paired Bluetooth device and internal speakers WITHOT losing pairing.

Comment: Yes - I have three Bluetooth devices paired and can connect / disconnect them at will from macOS - that’s how it’s been implemented as far back as I can remember.

Comment: I have Phonak HAs also.  If I pair them with my 2015 iMac/Monterey, then pair them with the iPhone, when I return to the iMac, I have to open the BT panel, then restart the HAs to pair them.  It's been that way for me since Catallina.